# Is the category of categories a topos?

Tags: category-theory

The 2-category of small categories is the archetypal example of a 2-topos (whatever that is). But what about the 1-category of small categories? Is it a topos? A 2-topos? Something else?

Comment: It is not a 2-topos in the sense of Lurie (which is a (2, 1)-category).

Comment: @ZhenLin, So what is it?

Comment: It is a 2-topos in the sense of Street, which seems to be the more natural sense for someone without Lurie's particular goals.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Can you elaborate in an answer what is a 2-topos in the sense of Street (w.r.t. a 1-topos) and how $Cat$ fits the description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (Grothendieck) 2-topos (a la Street) is a 2-category equivalent to the 2-category of sheaves on a 2-site. Such sheaves are 2-functors from a small 2-category to the small category of categories, where a 2-sheaf is defined analogously to a sheaf, but takes a few more steps to define: the limit in question is more complex, both because we're in a 2-category and because there are three levels of separation between presheaf and sheaf, instead of two as in the 1-categorical case.

Then Cat is simply the sheaves on a point with its canonical topology. Note this says nothing about the underlying 1-category.

Answer (score 5):

I thought I would add here an elementary proof that $\mathbf{Cat}$ has no subobject classifier.  (This would be as a complement to the other answers which redirect to an MO post, which further redirect to literature references.)

(I'm also posting this as a community wiki since it has minimal changes from my answer to [the corresponding question for the category of groupoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120698/is-the-2-category-of-groupoids-a-topos/3120818), so it didn't seem appropriate to get additional reputation points from this copy.)

So, first note that the object functor $\operatorname{Ob} : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is representable by the category $1$ with one object and one (identity) morphism.  Similarly, the arrows functor $\operatorname{Arr} : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is representable by the category $A$ with two objects $s,t$, and three morphisms (one identity morphism $s \to s$, one morphism $s \to t$, one identity morphism $t \to t$) with the unique composition.  In particular, given any monomorphism $F : C \to D$ in $\mathbf{Cat}$, this implies that $\operatorname{Ob}(F)$ and $\operatorname{Arr}(F)$ are injective functions, from which it is straightforward to conclude that $F$ is a composition of an isomorphism from $C$ to a subcategory of $D$ with the inclusion functor into $D$.  This implies that $\mathbf{Cat}$ is well-powered, with $\operatorname{Sub}(C)$ being the set of subcategories of $C$.

Now, suppose that $\mathbf{Cat}$ had a subobject classifier $\Omega$.  Then we would have to have:
$$\operatorname{Ob}(\Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(1, \Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}(1) = \{ 1, \emptyset \}$$
and
$$\operatorname{Arr}(\Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A, \Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}(A) = \{ A, A_d, \{ s \}, \{ t \}, \emptyset \}.$$
Here $A_d$ represents the subcategory with objects $s$ and $t$, and only the identity morphisms.

Also, the source and target morphisms $s, t : \operatorname{Arr} \to \operatorname{Ob}$ are induced by the functors $1 \to A$ corresponding to $s, t \in \operatorname{Ob}(A)$, respectively.  From this, we can see that:
$$ A \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}(1, 1) \\
A_d \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}(1, 1) \\
\{ s \} \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}(1, \emptyset) \\
\{ t \} \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}(\emptyset, 1) \\
\emptyset \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}(\emptyset, \emptyset).$$

We now consider the category corresponding to the poset $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ with the induced order, and the subcategory corresponding to the poset $\{ 0, 2 \}$.  We then want to find a morphism $F : \{ 0, 1, 2 \} \to \Omega$ such that $\{ 0, 2 \}$ is the pullback of this morphism and $\top : 1 \to \Omega$ (which must correspond to the object 1 of $\Omega$).  We must have $F(0) = 1, F(1) = \emptyset, F(2) = 0$ so $F(0 \le 1) = \{ s \}$, $F(1 \le 2) = \{ t \}$.  Thus, $F(0 \le 2) = \{ t \} \circ \{ s \}$.

But if we repeat the same argument with the subcategory $\{ 0, 2 \}$ with no morphism $0 \to 2$, we will find that for this subobject also with corresponding functor $F' : \{ 0, 1, 2 \} \to \Omega$, $F' = F$.  This contradicts the fact that $F'$ and $F$ must give different pullbacks.

---

Note that the construction of $\Omega$ above gives a perfectly good subobject classifier for the category of directed graphs.  (In fact, this category is equivalent to the category of functors $AOst \to \mathbf{Set}$ where $AOst$ is the category with two objects $A,O$ generated by two morphisms $s, t : A \to O$, so it is a topos.)  Given a subgraph $G'$ of $G$, to get the corresponding morphism $G \to \Omega$, we map objects of $G$ to 1 if they are in $G'$ and to $\emptyset$ otherwise.  And for edges in $G$, if the source or target is not in $G'$ then the edge also cannot be in $G'$ and correspondingly, there is exactly one element of the $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Omega}$ set; otherwise, if the source and target are in $G'$, then we send that edge to $A$ if the edge is in $G'$, and to $A_d$ otherwise.

What the argument above says is essentially: if we try to extend this to categories, then the problem we get is that if neither $f$ nor $g$ is in the subcategory and neither is the common target of $f$ and source of $g$, but the source of $f$ and the target of $g$ are, then that is not enough information to determine whether $g \circ f$ is in the subcategory.  However, if there were a subcategory classifier $\Omega$, it would end up having to agree with the subgraph classfier at the graph level, and then the composition law within that $\Omega$ would have to determine that $g \circ f$ is either always in the subcategory or never in it.  (And we could make a similar argument for the case where the common target of $f$ and source of $g$ is in the subcategory.)

Answer (score 1):

Cat is obviously Cartesian closed and has finite limits, so if it has a subobject classifier, it's a topos. Unfortunately, [it does not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28747/lattice-of-subcategories-subobject-classifier-in-cat).

Comment: This partly answers my question. So what is $Cat$?

Comment: @Bob This is a very late response, but $\mathsf{Cat}$ (as a 1-category) is what Joyal calls a para-topos. If you think about the characterization of Grothendieck toposes as localizations of a presheaf category whose localization preserves finite limits, and if you weaken this by only requiring that the localization preserves finite products, then you end up with para-toposes. See this [talk](https://youtu.be/qmCh9KwrQq8).