# Is the 2-category of groupoids a topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, groupoids

I have no justification for this, but I am wondering if the 2-category of groupoids is a topos.

Comment: I remember reading some passing comments about the category of groupoids forming a model of the Calculus of Constructions not satisfying the axiom of uniqueness of equality proofs (so this model might also be mentioned in HoTT literature, as far as I know).  And since the theory of Calculus of Constructions is stronger than the theory of a topos, my guess would be "yes".

Comment: A topos is defined as a 1-category. Do you mean the 1-category of groupoids? Or are you asking if the 2-category of groupoids is a [2-topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-topos)?

Comment: I guess I am asking, "is the 2-category of groupoids a 2-topos?".  I didn't know that a 2-category had to be a 2-topos (if it were any kind of topos).

Comment: @BenSprott the 2-category of groupoids is indeed a $(2,1)$-topos, but under the most accessible definitions this is a tautology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the category you're considering has small groupoids as objects and functors between them as morphisms, with equality of morphisms being exact equality of functors: then this category has no subobject classifier.

To see why, note that the objects functor $\operatorname{Ob} : \mathbf{Groupoids} \to \mathbf{Sets}$ is representable by the groupoid $1$ with one object and one morphism.  Similarly, the arrows functor $\operatorname{Arr} : \mathbf{Groupoids} \to \mathbf{Sets}$ is representable by the groupoid $2$ with two objects and four morphisms (one between each pair of objects).  In particular, given any monomorphism $F : G_1 \to G_2$, we then have that $\operatorname{Ob}(F)$ and $\operatorname{Arr}(F)$ are injective functions, which implies that $F$ is the composition of an isomorphism from $G_1$ to a subgroupoid of $G_2$ and the inclusion functor for that subgroupoid.  It follows that $\mathbf{Groupoids}$ is well-powered, with $\operatorname{Sub}(G)$ being the set of subgroupoids of $G$.

Now, suppose we had a subclassifier object $\Omega$ of $\mathbf{Groupoids}$.  Then we would have to have:
$$\operatorname{Ob}(\Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(1, \Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}(1) = \{ \emptyset, 1 \} $$
and
$$\operatorname{Arr}(\Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(2, \Omega) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}(2).$$
Now, the subgroupoids of 2 are: 2 itself; the disconnected groupoid $2_d$ with the two objects of 2 but no morphisms between them; the groupoid $\{ 0 \}$ with the first object from 2; the groupoid $\{ 1 \}$ with the second object from 2; and the empty groupoid.  Furthermore, the source and destination morphisms $\operatorname{Arr} \to \operatorname{Ob}$ are induced by the morphisms $1 \to 2$ mapping the object of 1 to $0 \in \operatorname{Ob}(2)$, respectively $1 \in \operatorname{Ob}(2)$.  Therefore, we must have:
$$ 2 \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Omega(1, 1); \\ 2_d \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Omega(1, 1); \\ \{ 0 \} \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Omega(1, \emptyset); \\ \{ 1 \} \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Omega(\emptyset, 1); \\ \emptyset \in \operatorname{Hom}_\Omega(\emptyset, \emptyset).$$
This means that $\Omega$ has a morphism from $\emptyset$ to 1, but $\operatorname{End}_\Omega(\emptyset)$ and $\operatorname{End}_\Omega(1)$ are not isomorphic groups, giving a contradiction.

---

If, on the other hand, the category you're considering has small groupoids as objects, with morphisms being isomorphism classes of functors - then I'm not sure what the answer would be in that case.  (In this case, the global sections functor $\operatorname{Hom}(1, -)$ would be the connected components functor.  The functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, -)$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the single-object groupoid with morphisms $\mathbb{Z}$, would then give some information about the $\pi_1$ groups.)

Comment: The second category you describe doesn't even have equalizers.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I've been finding it hard to reason about that second category. If you could post an answer indicating why it doesn't have equalizers, that could make a good complement to my answer.

Comment: I think it's a bit off-topic to post as an answer, since it doesn't seem the OP was asking about the second category. But there's a counterexample here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ho%28Cat%29#OtherLimits