# Is the category of topoi a topos?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

To be clear, I mean the category $\mathbf{Topoi}$ whose objects are all elementary topoi, and whose morphisms are logical functors between topoi. Does this category itself form a topos? What about the category $\mathbf{Groth}$ of Grothendieck topoi (with geometric morphisms)? If yes, do either of these categories form a Grothendieck topos?

I see that $\mathbf{Cat}$ [does not form a topos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742667/is-the-category-of-categories-a-topos).

Comment: I guess you want to forget the 2-cells; now, is a morphism of toposes the inverse or the direct image of a geometric morphism? What is a monomorphism between toposes? Just a monomorphism as an arrow of $\bf Cat$?

Comment: The category of Grothendieck topoi is not a topos, because it is not locally cartesian closed (cf. Niefield's [Exponentiable Morphisms: Posets, Spaces, Locales, And Grothendieck Toposes](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n2/n2.pdf)).